# How to restrict admin js files to download

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc

If i create my angular app with user + admin pages
user can see the admin pages under the hood.

let say i create sperated admin app, if the user have the url he still can get the admin pages under the hood

how to completely prevent that download of admin pages without password?